# Why do I have to use 'arch -arm64' before brew terminal commands on m1?

Tags: ruby, react-native, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I am literally fighting for my life to get this machine setup for react native development. There have been crazy amount of problems and brew install do not work without arch -arm64. Is this a problem? Why is this?
PS: I am new to mac OS

Its just a question for knowledge

Comment: "This is not a problem, this is a feature" :) M1 is an ARM-based processor (or, to be more precise, system-on-a-chip), so it implements a completely different (reduced) instruction set architecture than more common Intel/AMD CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to take a look at this repo, [mac-dev-setup](https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup). All the formulae are pretty well maintained in the homebrew-core.

If you have further doubt, you can also raise in the [discussions](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/) to get quicker response.